# Como obter nome dos objetos contidos no JSON com Java?

Tags: java, json

Precisava extrair o nome dos objetos contidos em um arquivo JSON, por exemplo, mostrar que o arquivo JSON abaixo possui os objetos batteryCharge, luminousFlux, id, temperature. Mas efetuar essa busca sem especificar o nome do objeto a ser procurado, pois tenho outros arquivos JSON com objetos diferentes.

```
{
    "batteryCharge": {
        "metadata": {
            "code": {
                "type": "Text",
                "value": "%"
            }
        },
        "type": "urn:x-ogc:def:phenomenon:IDAS:1.0:batteryCharge",
        "value": "74"
    },
    "id": "urn:smartsantander:testbed:338",
    "luminousFlux": {
        "metadata": {
            "code": {
                "type": "Text",
                "value": "lm"
            }
        },
        "type": "urn:x-ogc:def:phenomenon:IDAS:1.0:luminousFlux",
        "value": "0"
    },
    "temperature": {
        "metadata": {
            "code": {
                "type": "Text",
                "value": "Cel"
            }
        },
        "type": "urn:x-ogc:def:phenomenon:IDAS:1.0:temperature",
        "value": "90"
    }
}
```

obter este resultado:

```
batteryCharge, luminousFlux, id, temperature
```

Desde já, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um colega me ajudou aqui... consegui o resultado que queria com essa função:

```
package buscaJson;

import java.io.*;
import org.json.*;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class BuscaAtributos {

public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

         try {

                Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("teste.json"));

                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
                System.out.println(jsonObject.keySet()); 

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Resultado obtido:

```
[batteryCharge, temperature, id, luminousFlux]
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o `Gson`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

se quiser converter o json inteiro para object vai precisar estruturar as classes:

code

```
public class Code {
    private String type;
    private String value;

   //gets e sets

}
```

metadata

```
public class Metadata {
    private Code code;

   //gets e sets

}
```

data

```
public class Data {
    private Metadata metadata;
    private String type;
    private String value;

   //gets e sets

}
```

e seu objecto

```
public class MyOBJ {

    private String id;
    private Data batteryCharge;
    private Data luminousFlux;
    private Data temperature;

   //gets e sets

}
```

para utilizar a conversão do json para o object basta fazer desta forma:

```
MyOBJ obj = new Gson().fromJson(json, MyOBJ.class);
```

Outra forma é trabalhar direto com o json, vc pode utilizar a `org.json`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>
```

e trabalhar com os objetos desta forma:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

    JSONObject batteryCharge = jsonObject.getJSONObject("batteryCharge");
    JSONObject luminousFlux = jsonObject.getJSONObject("luminousFlux");
    String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
    JSONObject temperature = jsonObject.getJSONObject("temperature");
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão!